# Symfony creates empty association when checkbox used on embedded form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form for `Person` that has an embedded form for `Address` (bi-directional one to one relationship, with `Address` as the owning side w/ FK).

If a user submits the form, Symfony will initialize an empty `Address` object and assign it to the `$address` property on the `$person` object. Instead, I want Symfony to recognize all the form fields for `Address` were blank and it should NOT initialize an empty `Address` object.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** I discovered that this only happens when I have a checkbox on the embedded form type. If there is no checkbox, Symfony will NOT create an empty association object. I think the problem is an unchecked checkbox is assumed to be a "false" value, so Symfony has no choice but to interpret that as a submitted value. Still looking for a reasonable workaround.

Comment: are you using doctrine?

Comment: Yes I'm using doctrine

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with form events

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Search for FORM_SUBMIT

However, I find it a bit convoluted.

Consider instead treating Person and Address as independent objects then setting the relation in your controller after checking Address.  Something like:

```
$person = new Person();
$address = new Address();
$formData = array('person' => $person, 'address' => $address);

$builder = $this->formFactory->create('form',$formData);

$builder->add('person',  new PersonFormType());
$builder->add('address', new AddressFormType());

...
if ($form->isValid()
{
    if ($address was filled in properly)
    {
        $person->setAddress($address);
    }
---
```

I find the above approach a bit easier to understand than going through the form event stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion here. I was trying to avoid the `$address was filled in properly` check, since it would involve checking the values of every item in the associated form.